# After permitting All to a route, stil getting forbidden in Spring securoty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm using spring boot `3.2.0`. I'm trying to to JWT Based Authentication wth spring security. For that I have defined a JWT based Authentication filter. The problem is there is a route `/auths/public/**`, I want to permit all to this route. For this in the security config I have done:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class SecurityConfiguration {
        private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
        private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests((authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                                    .requestMatchers("/auths/inner/**").hasRole(Role.INNER_SERVICE.name()) // Selectively permitted for users with role INNER_SERVICE with authentication
                                    .requestMatchers("/auths/authenticated/**").hasRole(Role.USER.name()) // Selectively permitted for users with role USER with authentication
                                    .requestMatchers("/auths/public/**").permitAll() // All requests are permitted
                                    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // All requests are permitted
                                    .anyRequest().permitAll() // All other routes are permitted (!! security alert)
            ))
                    .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

This is the JWT custom filter I have written:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        // for public urls
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        // To cut out the "Bearer " part
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt, true);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            // user present but not authenticated yet
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails, true)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                        null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

This main part here is this couple of lines:

```java
http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests((authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                                    .requestMatchers("/auths/inner/**").hasRole(Role.INNER_SERVICE.name()) // Selectively permitted for users with role INNER_SERVICE with authentication
                                    .requestMatchers("/auths/authenticated/**").hasRole(Role.USER.name()) // Selectively permitted for users with role USER with authentication
                                    .requestMatchers("/auths/public/**").permitAll() // All requests are permitted
                                    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // All requests are permitted
                                    .anyRequest().permitAll() // All other routes are permitted (!! security alert)
            ))
                    .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
```

Here you can see I have permitted all for the route `/auths/public` but when I do a request like:

**POST** `http://localhost:5000/auths/public/send?message=Hello_Kafka`
I get:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-15T18:42:16.607+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/auths/public/send"
}
```

These are the logs that I get for this request:

```bash
2024-01-16 00:12:16.495 
d9814d3abe2031bb
2024-01-16T00:12:16.495+05:30  WARN [auth,0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be,d9814d3abe2031bb] 47661 --- [auth] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] [0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be-d9814d3abe2031bb] o.s.w.s.h.HandlerMappingIntrospector     : Cache miss for ERROR dispatch to '/error' (previous null). Performing MatchableHandlerMapping lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.
2024-01-16 00:12:16.550 
afab4ea55ae080f6
2024-01-16T00:12:16.550+05:30 DEBUG [auth,0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be,afab4ea55ae080f6] 47661 --- [auth] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] [0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be-afab4ea55ae080f6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error?message=Hello_Kafka", parameters={masked}
2024-01-16 00:12:16.558 
afab4ea55ae080f6
2024-01-16T00:12:16.558+05:30 DEBUG [auth,0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be,afab4ea55ae080f6] 47661 --- [auth] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] [0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be-afab4ea55ae080f6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-01-16 00:12:16.619 
afab4ea55ae080f6
2024-01-16T00:12:16.619+05:30 DEBUG [auth,0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be,afab4ea55ae080f6] 47661 --- [auth] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] [0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be-afab4ea55ae080f6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-01-16 00:12:16.629 
afab4ea55ae080f6
2024-01-16T00:12:16.629+05:30 DEBUG [auth,0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be,afab4ea55ae080f6] 47661 --- [auth] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] [0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be-afab4ea55ae080f6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Jan 16 00:12:16 IST 2024, status=403, error=Forbidden, message=Forbidden, path=/auths (truncated)...]
2024-01-16 00:12:16.659 
afab4ea55ae080f6
2024-01-16T00:12:16.659+05:30 DEBUG [auth,0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be,afab4ea55ae080f6] 47661 --- [auth] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] [0ac98fa25129402e7442fba23c5552be-afab4ea55ae080f6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
```

From the logs I can see the request I'm sending is going to error handler for some reason, I can't understand why.

For the entire codebase: [Hangout-Auth-Service](https://github.com/opticSquid/hangout-auth-service/tree/updated-workflow), checkout the `updated-workflow` branch here.

[This compose file will help you setup other dependency services](https://github.com/opticSquid/hangout/blob/dev/docker-compose.yaml)

Additional services required to setup:

[Service Discovery](https://github.com/opticSquid/hangout-service-discovery/tree/dev), checkout the `dev` branch here.

[Application Gateway](https://github.com/opticSquid/hangout-gateway/tree/dev), checkout the `dev` branch here.

Comment: If there is any more details you need feel free to comment I will give the details

Comment: you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous, and unsecure, JWTs are not meant to be used in browsers. There is a reason the thing you have built is not by default implemented in spring security So why are you building an unsecure dangerous application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the security filter chain disable csrf mainly but here I have disabled cors too for dev mode. This error is mainly coming for csrf not matching because in request I'm not passing any csrf token.

So, securityFilterChain changes to:

```java
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests((authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                                .requestMatchers("/auths/inner/**").hasRole(Role.INNER_SERVICE.name()) // Selectively permitted for users with role INNER_SERVICE with authentication
                                .requestMatchers("/auths/authenticated/**").hasRole(Role.USER.name()) // Selectively permitted for users with role USER with authentication
                                .requestMatchers("/auths/public/**").permitAll() // All requests are permitted
                                .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // All requests are permitted
                                .anyRequest().permitAll() // All other routes are permitted (!! security alert)
        ))
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to [configure or disable csrf](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html) through you filter. That is why you get this error I think.
For more details about this type of error you can enable spring security log in your config file with that config:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE
```

You can try this to disable csrf through filter:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws 
  Exception {
      http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
    //...
}
```

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: yes you are correct I found out after I went through the logs in trace level

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with this. After researching from my point of view, I think the `permitAll()` means whether the user role or privilege, but it still needs an auth. It does not mean you can visit the resource without authorization.

If you need to set a whitelist, consider using the ignoring configuration.

Here is a demo, it should solve your problem.

```java
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers("/auths/public/**");
}
```